# centering content of iframe for a content body of a specific width

Tags: html, css, iframe

another Question maybe impossible to answer:
on my webside I have an `iframe` in a div-container:

**div:**

```
<div id='frame'>
    <iframe id='content' name='contentfield' ></iframe>
</div>
```

In the `css` file there is:

**css:**

```
div#frame{
position:absolute;
display:flex;
background-color:green;(just for my testing)
top:100px;
float:left;
width:calc(100vw - 200px);
height:calc(100vh - 100px);
}
iframe#content{
border:none;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

This `iframe` shows different sides of my webside, e.g. index.php (many index.php's)
so one is loaded by the `javascript`:

```
function start(id){active = id;
    document.getElementById('content').src='content/hallo/';
}
```

so there is: content/hallo/index.php.
The `index.php` is a normal `html` document, but body is set to a specific width in px:

```
<body style='width:1000px'>
    ...
</body>
```

Now: If the browser window is larger then 1200px(100px from body and 200px from another div, see div#frame) the content of the `iframe` has the width of 1000px but floated left. I want it to be centered so that if the browser window is 1600px wide the content has a margin-left=margin-right of 200px a.s.o.

Edit:
screenshot that shows the unwished:
[darkgray is the menu, light gray the iframe and, as you guess right, the pic i a part of me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvFqi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:You will set the following property

```
max-width:auto;
```

Comment: Tryed to add this to div#frame, iframe#content, body style=".." nothing worked, so either i am to stupid to see where to put it in or this is not the solution^^

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience when html5 didn't support the align attribute on the iframe that let you control position. I solved it with `display:block` and `margin:auto` on the iframe.

Since you have a width 1000px on the body then that will always pull left (causing everything inside to appear more to the left because it is centered within the body) unless you add margin to that as well to push it into the center.

```css
.frame{
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
min-height:100vh;
}

iframe{
display:block;
margin:auto;
height:100vh;
min-height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id='frame'>
    <iframe id='content' name='contentfield' align="center"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I have made a nice screenshot of the results of your suggestion, but the comment function don't seem to add picture to it, so you can't see my 'hair' :D. So in word: It doe not work. I get the same result like in the first answer: The frame is reduced to ... i guess 200px?? But the 200px are centered^^. So i guess i forget something to tell you but i dont know what. Give me some time to figure out what i miss to tell you...

Comment: You can revise your original question to have a screenshot. Are you concerned the iframe is too short or the .frame class that is the parent container? You should be able to add 'min-height:100vh' to it with CSS and it may solve your issue. If the issue persists I can only assume it is other styles within your project affecting it in an unforeseen manner.

I have edited my above answer with min height added to both parent container and Iframe that is inside of it.

Comment: Heyo, have added a pic to the main post. Maybe its easier to understand what i do not xD. The box with my hair is the iframe build by your or Roshan's suggestion. But: I want the box of the iframe to be about the complete width, but the "sub-page" shown in the iframe to be not about 100% of the width, maybe 50% or something else, but centerd in the box of the iframe so that the iframe goes from the darkgray (left) to the end of the right, the text and the picture but centered with a smaller width in it. Damn max comment length ...

Comment: Comment 2: The idea behind this construcion a a complex animation wth fquerry inside a index.php loaded into the iframe. The jquerry animation is based on fixed pixels an has a total width of 1000. The rest f the page, exspacially the conatiner ist variable in its width so that the iframe gets a horizontal scrollbar when the browserwindow is smaller then 1200px(200 for the menu) and 1000px if the browser width is larger then 1200px. It all works fine, but the animation is not centered in the iframe, it is flushed left in the iframe.....

Comment: I can't wrap my head around what you're trying to accomplish. Sorry.